# Cuál es el proverbio "el papel no sangra" que mencionan en Por Quién Doblan Las Campanas

Tags: etimología, significado, historia

Al final del capítulo 11 de *[Por Quién Doblan Las Campanas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Por_qui%C3%A9n_doblan_las_campanas)* de Ernest Hemingway, Robert Jordan haciendo referencia a un proverbio dice la frase

> El papel no sangra.

Pilar dice después

> Pero es muy útil.

Quisiera saber si existe tal proverbio y su significado. Realmente no le encuentro mucho sentido. Busqué en la web pero no encuentro nada relacionado.

Comment: Un poco de contexto facilitaría entender (o intentar entender) el significado que buscas. ¿En relación a qué dice Robert esa frase (sea un proverbio o no)? ¿Tal vez algo que discute con el Sordo?

Comment: Siendo que la frase que citas en español es de una traducción, sería útil saber la frase y su contexto en el inglés original de Hemingway para entender por qué intentó el traductor expresarla de tal manera. Los proverbios, si era proverbio inglés, son muchas veces difíciles de traducir con el sentido o efecto original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No encuentro referencias a la existencia de ese supuesto proverbio ni en español ni en inglés.

He encontrado [un interesante comentario](https://books.google.es/books?id=LPZfi4ADcusC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=paper%20bleeds%20little%20proverb&source=bl&ots=tgcBQh0oPV&sig=ACfU3U2BkDNqs28Ksr1oguzf68bqgG_l6g&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip1tehuJTzAhVwyoUKHZHoAVUQ6AF6BAgbEAM#v=onepage&q=paper%20bleeds%20little%20proverb&f=false) al respecto en el libro [The Dictionary of Modern Proverbs](https://books.google.es/books?id=LPZfi4ADcusC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false), compilado por Charles C.Doyle, Wolfgang Mieder y Fred Shapiro.

Permitidme citarlo y traducirlo

> Paper bleeds little (Paper does not bleed)
>  1940 Ernest Hemingway, *For
> Whom the Bell Tolls* (New York: Charles Scribner's Sons) 166: "On paper
> the bridge is blown at the moment the attack starts ... It is very
> simple.' That they should let us do something on paper.' El Sordo said
> ... "Paper bleeds little."' Robert Jordan quoted the proverb" (the
> reader is probably expected to assume that a Spanish proverb has been
> quoted, although- thanks, perhaps, to the novel's popularity- it has
> become common in English).
>  *1974 Palm Beach [FL] Post* 27 Jan:"The
> Spanish had a saying during their civil war that paper doesn't bleed-
> a reference to maps and orders from headquarters as opposed to
> soldiers in the lines."

Mi traducción sería

> El papel sangra poco (El papel no sangra)
>  1940 Ernest Hemingway, *Por
> Quien Doblan Las Campanas* (Nueva York: Charles Scribner's Sons) 166:
> "Sobre el papel se vuela el puente en cuanto comienza el ataque ... Es
> muy sencillo.' Como si nos dejaran hacer algo sobre el papel.' dijo El
> Sordo ... "El papel sangra poco." citó el proverbio Robert Jordan" (se supone que el lector asumirá que un proverbio español ha sido citado, aunque -gracias, quizás, a la popularidad de la novela- se ha hecho común en inglés)
>
> *1974 Palm Beach [FL] Post* 27 Jan: "Los españoles tenían un dicho durante su guerra civil: el papel no sangra - una referencia a los mapas y las ordenes del cuartel general en contraste con los soldados en el frente."

Señaladme cualquier mejora en relación a esta traducción.

Las diferencias entre dicho y proverbio en español me resultan muy sutiles, consultando el significado en el DLE podemos concluir que son sinónimos.

> [**proverbio**](https://dle.rae.es/proverbio)
>
> 1. m. Sentencia, adagio o **refrán**.

> [**refrán**](https://dle.rae.es/refr%C3%A1n)
>
> 1. m. **Dicho** agudo y sentencioso de uso común.

Como curiosidad, en mi trabajo hemos adaptado inadvertidamente este dicho y lo hemos aplicado a nuestro ámbito de la informática y la programación para reflejar el contraste entre los ingenieros funcionales (el cuartel general) y los programadores (en primera línea)

> El (documento) Word siempre compila y despliega

Comment: @Alcor No sé, con el título del libro mítico ya hay bastante contexto. Un libro centrado en unos guerrilleros comandados por un extranjero durante la Guerra Civil Española. A partir de la frase se puede encontrar el párrafo si es necesario.

Comment: @Alcor Podría haber incluido más contexto o menos. El OP no está obligado a reaccionar a todos los comentarios y requerimientos. Tú ya habías encontrado el texto dentro del libro, ¿Por qué insistir en pedírselo al OP de nuevo pudiendo incluirlo tú mismo en tu respuesta?

Comment: Bueno, esa es tu opinión. Yo tengo la mía. Nadie te obliga ti a buscar nada. Pero si ya lo has encontrado, no tiene sentido insistir. Pon el texto tú en tu respuesta, edita la pregunta y complétala o ponle un comentario indicando que en el futuro procure incluir algo de contexto. Yo con el libro y ¿"El papel no sangra" es un proverbio? ya lo veo bien.

Comment: @Alcor No entiendo tu política (o la del moderador, si no eres tú) de borrar comentarios. Pero bueno, allá cada uno ...

Comment: (+1) With the full context it seems fairly clear that this is not an accepted proverb but a witticism from El Sordo.

Comment: @mdewey Notice that the original question is in Spanish. In Spanish there is no difference between dicho and proverbio, as I've stated above. In any case, I agree with you, it's a witticism and not a proverb, accordint to the meanings compiled in the Oxford Dictionary for those words.

Answer (score 1):

---

Que tal? sobre la frase "El papel no sangra".

Robert Jordan haciendo referencia a un proverbio dice la frase El papel no sangra.

Exactamente dice;

—El papel no sangra —dijo Robert Jordan, citando el proverbio.

Pilar dice después
Pero es muy útil.

La pregunta es;

*Quisiera saber si existe tal proverbio y su significado*.

---

Cuando Robert Jordan dice "El papel no sangra", se esta refiriendo a una expresión que ya existe y que todos conocen, haciendo obvio una limitación del mismo papel, que sin embargo y a pesar de todo, no puede llevar a cabo como es la de sangrar.

Para comprender mejor la expresión, debemos retroceder unos renglones en el texto.

Léase el siguiente párrafo;

—No hablemos de eso —dijo el Sordo—. Estamos aquí para hacer lo que
se pueda. Pero la cosa es peliaguda.

—Sobre el papel, sin embargo, es muy sencilla —dijo Robert Jordan
sonriendo—. Sobre el papel, el puente tiene que saltar en el momento en que
comience el ataque, de modo que no pueda llegar nada por la carretera. Es
muy sencillo.

—Que nos hagan hacer alguna cosa sobre el papel —dijo el Sordo—, que
inventen y realicen algo sobre el papel.
—El papel no sangra —dijo Robert Jordan, citando el proverbio.

—Pero es muy útil —dijo Pilar—
...

---

La expresión ó dicho al que todos se están refiriendo es;

"**El papel lo puede todo**" que significa que en un papel puede que figuren cuestiones que a la hora de ponerlas en práctica, difícilmente pueden llevarse por muy bien que estén en ellos (los papeles) representados y tengan acogida en ellos. Y es que “el papel lo aguanta todo”.

En este sentido se refiere la frase anterior;
—*Sobre el papel, sin embargo, es muy sencilla —dijo Robert Jordan
sonriendo—. Sobre el papel, el puente tiene que saltar en el momento en que
comience el ataque...*

Igualmente, cuando dice el Sordo;
—*Que nos hagan hacer alguna cosa sobre el papel —dijo el Sordo—, que
inventen y realicen algo sobre el papel*.

Y al final Pilar pone de relieve que;

*—"Pero es muy útil —dijo Pilar"—*

Refiriéndose a que a pesar de ello, que no lo aguante a todo, en alusión a que el papel no sangra, es decir, no puede con todo, sin embargo, es útil tener las cosas sobre un papel, aunque ello no signifique que se cumplan ó salgan bien todas las cosas que hay en el expuestas.

*El papel lo aguanta todo, las personas no*. Sobre un papel se puede poner lo que uno quiera o desea, pero que se cumpla, que lo que en él aparezca sea cierto, que pueda ayudar a poner las cosas en marcha ó llevarlo a cabo sin contratiempos ó imprevistos, es una cosa bien distinta, por tanto, el papel aunque puede con todo aquello que en él aparece escrito, sin embargo, lo que no puede es sangrar.

Dicho de otra manera, *el papel no sangra*  viene a equilibrar el dicho "el papel lo puede todo", que en este contexto, significa que a pesar de que en el papel se pongan todos los puntos que hay que realizar por escrito, el papel no puede hacerlo todo, no puede llevarlo a cabo por si solo, se necesitan personas que se arriesguen, lo hagan realidad y desgraciadamente mueran ó sean heridas (sangre), aunque mantener las cosas solo por escrito sin llevarlas a cabo (no sangren), siempre ayuda y es útil, como dice Pilar.

El origen de la frase parece estar en una contestación que hizo Carlos I de España y V de Alemania a Francisco I de Francia.

Espero haya acarado el término. Saludos.

Diego M.